# Email Multiple Recipients VBA Error

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

Looking for help with sending emails to a list of people.  My code has a simple loop and grabs the value each time through of where to send the email.  While testing, the first email will always get sent. After that, the 2nd time through I get error on ".To"

**`Run-time error - '-2147221238 (8004010a):`**
The item has been moved or deleted.

This is puzzling to me because the code does accurately grab the next email value?

The emails need to be sent one by one, instead of adding the recipients to a list of bcc. Is this possible with VBA?  Thanks in advance!

```
Sub TestingAgain()

'Setting up the Excel variables.
 Dim outApp As Object
Dim outMailItem As Object
Dim iCounter As Integer
Dim sDest As String
Dim sName As String

'Create the Outlook application and the empty email.
Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set outMailItem = outApp.CreateItem(0)

With outMailItem
    sDest = ""
For i = 2 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1))
    If i <> "" Then
        'Grab first name and email
        sDest = Cells(i, 5).Value
        sName = Cells(i, 1).Value

        'Send each email
        .To = sDest
        .Subject = "FYI"
        .htmlbody = "Some stuff"
        .Send
    Else
    MsgBox ("Error")

    End If
Next i

End With

'Clean up the Outlook application.
Set outMailItem = Nothing
Set outApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send the e-mail, the `mailItem` instance is done and not available anymore. Refactor your code like :

```
Sub TestingAgain()

    'Setting up the Excel variables.
     Dim outApp As Object
    Dim outMailItem As Object
    Dim iCounter As Integer
    Dim sDest As String
    Dim sName As String

    'Create the Outlook application and the empty email.
    Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")



        sDest = ""
    For i = 2 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1))
        If i <> "" Then
        '/ Create the mail item instance.
        Set outMailItem = outApp.CreateItem(0)
        With outMailItem
                'Grab first name and email
                sDest = Cells(i, 5).Value
                sName = Cells(i, 1).Value

                'Send each email
                .To = sDest
                .Subject = "FYI"
                .htmlbody = "Some stuff"
                .send
                '/ Once sent, mail item is no more available.
            End With
            Else
            MsgBox ("Error")

            End If

    Next


    'Clean up the Outlook application.
    Set outMailItem = Nothing
    Set outApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: That's perfect.  Thank you.  So in this line of code:
Set outMailItem = outApp.CreateItem(0)
The "0" in CreateItem is just a starting point to get things moving?

Comment: yw. No that `0` is itemtype parameter value, see this for more clarity: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869291.aspx